# How to count from 0.0001 to 1 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point-precision

I want to count from 0.0001 to 1 with 0.0001 steps in ruby.
I wrote this code but it enters to an infinite loop. Somewhy the interpreter does a wrong summation.

```
x = 0.0001
while x != 1.0
  puts x
  x = x + 0.0001
end
```

Here is the first 10 value it gives:

```
0.0001
0.0002
0.00030000000000000003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006000000000000001
0.0007000000000000001
0.0008000000000000001
0.0009000000000000002
0.0010000000000000002
```

It should be 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, etc...
How can I make it working?
Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't happen on jruby.

Comment: gioele's answer is clearly better than the one you marked as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that real numbers in ruby are not represented exactly due to binary storage and manipulation. I would do this

```
x = 1
while x < 10000
    puts (x/10000).round(4)
    x += 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you!:) I just started programming. I didn't know that!:)

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't limited to Ruby, it's a floating point issue.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
0.0001.step(1, 0.0001).each { |i| puts i }
```

**EDIT**: you should use the `Float#step` method because it shields you from the weirdness of float arithmetic. `Float#step` will take care of incrementing the value and comparing to the limit in a float-proof way. For more information have a look at [the official documentation of `Float#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step).

Comment: Thank you! This makes the job:)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `x != 1.0`, put `x < 1.0`. That will at least be sure your loop ends.

A binary system like those that run all of our modern computers cannot (easily) represent fractions, especially ones that cannot be accurately represented in decimal. That is where the strange number comes in when you should have `.0003`. It is an artifact of how the numbers are represented internally.

Some languages are better at dealing with numbers and accuracy than others, so if the accuracy of the numbers matters, you either need to use a different language, use a library that handles the number things for you (significant digits and all that), or you need to handle it yourself with appropriate rounding, etc. at each step.

Comment: Yes it is working. But what to do if I want an accurate result?
And why 0.0005 + 0.0001 equals 0.0006000000000000001 to ruby?

Comment: Because of the way floating number works: have a look at http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not exactly accurate [Wikipedia Floating Point article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

If you must have clean x's, I'd recommend using an integer and dividing down by 1000 before you use the value.  If you don't care about the little bits of noise off, you'll be fine with changing your while x != 1.0 to while x < 1.0

Comment: I agree. In general, using integers for operations (if possible) and then converting down at the end will give more accurate results.

Comment: Common binary _representations_ of floating point numbers (e.g. IEEE 754) aren't accurate.

Comment: Michael, are you saying that the math is reliable but the output is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is due to binary representation of floating-point numbers. This affects all computer programming languages. For more detail see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

What you can do is round it to the appropriate number of digits at print time, or as goiele has found, use `step`:

```
0.0001.step(1, 0.0001).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I will read it through! And the code is also working fine:)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.step(10000, 1).each { |x| puts "%f" % (x / 10000.0).round(4) }
```